# Is ERC20ImplUpgradeable a Scam?

Tags: contract-design, tokens

I found this in GUSD Smart Contract.

The ERC20ImplUpgradeable means that the contract can always be changed. And our coin can be stolen whenever they wish without any trace.

If this is allowed by the community, then I will be implementing all my contracts following this same method.

It totally defeat the purposes of having a Smart Contract.

Answer (score 1):

Only some parts of the contract can be upgraded - depends on the actual implementation (not analyzing any specific instance now).

It's a rather common pattern and it's very useful for maintenance purposes. And yes, in some cases it may be abused. But that's all ok as it's all transparent - everyone can see the same "weakness" in the contracts.

There is no "community allowance" - you can write whatever you wish in your contract and deploy it - nobody can stop you even if they'd disagree with you. And that's exactly one of the beautiful sides in Ethereum - decentralization.

If you don't like some implementation, you don't have to use it. It may be a scam only if it's abused.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, the beautiful part of decentralization is not centrally control, and nobody can abuse it including the creator / owner.

Comment: You can abuse the system in any way possible, if you wish. There is no central authority to stop you. There are many examples of "abuse" which is totally ok as it's allowed by the EVM. There is not "right" or "wrong" - only what the system allows and what it doesn't.. The biggest debate about similar abuse was probably the ETC fork.

Comment: Abuse and deliberately abuse are different. I would consider this as a back door.